# Transcribing Splunk's "transaction" Command into Azure Log Analytics / Azure Data Analytics / Kusto

Tags: azure, splunk, azure-log-analytics

We're using AKS and have our container logs writing to Log Analytics. We have an application that emits several print statements in the container log per request, and we'd like to group all of those events/log lines into aggregate events, one event per incoming request, so it's easier for us to find lines of interest. So, for example, if the request started with the line "GET /my/app" and then later the application printed something about an access check, we want to be able to search through all the log lines for *that request* with something like `| where LogEntry contains "GET /my/app" and LogEntry contains "access_check"`.

I'm used to queries with Splunk. Over there, this type of inquiry would be a cinch to handle with the [`transaction` command](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.1.1/SearchReference/Transaction):
[image: example of "transaction" from Splunk documentation]

But, with Log Analytics, it seems like multiple commands are needed to pull this off. Seems like I need to use `extend` with `row_window_session` in order to give all the related log lines a common timestamp, then  `summarize` with `make_list` to group the lines of log output together into a JSON blob, then finally `parse_json` and `strcat_array` to assemble the lines into a newline-separated string.

Something like this:

```
ContainerLog
| sort by TimeGenerated asc
| extend RequestStarted= row_window_session(TimeGenerated, 30s, 2s, ContainerID != prev(ContainerID))
| summarize logLines = make_list(LogEntry) by RequestStarted
| extend parsedLogLines = strcat_array(parse_json(logLines), "\n")
| where parsedLogLines contains "GET /my/app" and parsedLogLines contains "access_check"
| project Timestamp=RequestStarted, LogEntry=parsedLogLines
```

Is there a better/faster/more straightforward way to be able to group multiple lines for the same request together into one event and then perform a search across the contents of that event?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question, there is no such an easy way to do that in azure log analytics.

If the logs are in this format, you need to do some other work to meet your requirement.